# What is the reason "When we create an index then CPU cost is less as compair to normal select query."?

Tags: database, oracle

Please suggest me answer for the mentioned query.
Q What is the reason 
    "When we create an index then CPU cost is less as compair to normal select query."?

Answer (score 2):

`When we create an index then CPU cost is less as compared to normal select query` **Is not always true.**

If indexes are not used to evaluate predicates (In the where clause), then there is no use of the index. In that case, consider creating new indexes or rewriting the statement or query so that indexes can be used. For example, indexes can only be used to evaluate WHERE clauses when single columns appear on one side of a comparison predicate (equalities and inequalities), or in a BETWEEN predicate. The presence of indexes does slow down write operations such as UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE and CREATE VIEW. If an application does few reads but many writes to a table, an index on that table may hurt overall performance rather than help it.

As per oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/indexes.htm), Indexes are optional structures associated with tables and clusters that allow SQL statements to execute more quickly against a table. Just as the index in this manual helps you locate information faster than if there were no index, an Oracle Database index provides a faster access path to table data. You can use indexes without rewriting any queries. Your results are the same, but you see them more quickly.

In general, create an index on a column in any of the following [situations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_indexes.htm):

The column is queried frequently.
A referential constraint exists on the column.
A UNIQUE key constraint exists on the column.

Indexes are logically and physically independent of the data in the associated table. Being independent structures, they require storage space. You can create or drop an index without affecting the base tables, database applications, or other indexes. The database automatically maintains indexes when you insert, update, and delete rows of the associated table. If you drop an index, all applications continue to work. However, access to previously indexed data might be slower.

This beautiful [article](http://www.orafaq.com/node/1403) explains more on indexes. Do have a read.

**Answering your question,** 
The logical reads per segment are all on index objects, if properly used. CPU performance is good when you read a table by Index since How oracle reads the blocks (and which blocks) with and without index is different.

Lets see how index work internally. Read more on this [document](http://www.dbafan.com/book/oracle_index_internals.pdf)

Consider a OLTP DB, with a table having B-Tree index. B-tree indexes are ordered lists of values divided into ranges with a key associated with a row or range of rows, thereby providing excellent retrieval performance for queries such as exact match and range searches.

This type of index contains 3 types of blocks - the root block, one or more branch blocks and one or more leaf blocks. The root block holds keys and pointers to the branch blocks which in turn hold pointers to the leaf blocks which contain the key (data) values that have been indexed and the rowids of the rows in the Oracle database table associated with each key value.

Branch blocks hold the minimum key prefix needed to be able to choose the required branch and a pointer to the child block containing the key. The number of keys and pointers is limited by the block size.

Index leaf blocks are double linked - each block contains pointers to the next and previous leaf blocks.

B-tree indexes are always balanced because the height of the index (the number of levels in the index) is the same throughout the index. In other words, the number of blocks that have to be read to find the rowid associated with any particular index value is not dependent on that value. For example if you had an index on the last_name column of the employee table in the sample Oracle database the number or blocks that would need to be read to find the rowid associated with "Ernst" would be the same as for "King".

The height of a b-tree index is the number of blocks required to go from the root block to a leaf block. For an index with one level of branch blocks the height is 3 (1 root block + 1 branch block + 1 leaf block).

> Other "common sense" things :

- rebuild indexes on a schedule.  everone knows indexes need to be rebuilt
- you must separate tables from indexes by tablespace, it is only common sense
- if your query is not using your indexes, the optimizer did the wrong thing

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from emp where deptno = 200;
```

Look how many comparisons with deptno 200 the CPU would have to do when querying the table without an index:

- Jones 100
- Miller 200
- Smith 100
- Blake 300
- Sawyer 300
- ...

Now the same with an index:

- 100 -> Jones, Smith, ...
- 200 -> Miller, ...
- 300 -> Sawyer, ...